# How do I fill in these missing keys with empty strings to get a complete Dataset?

Tags: dataset, associations

This is my original `data`:

```
data = {<|"GSMName" -> "GSM2142639", 
    "tumor (t) or normal (n)" -> "L886T", "stage tnm" -> "2", 
    "histology" -> "1", "surgery date" -> "2006-01-24", "age" -> "71",
     "gender" -> "male", "vital date" -> "2011-05-10", "dead" -> "1", 
    "smoking" -> "2", "ps who" -> "0"|>, <|"GSMName" -> "GSM2142640", 
    "tumor (t) or normal (n)" -> "L887T", "stage tnm" -> "1", 
    "histology" -> "2", "surgery date" -> "2007-11-06", "age" -> "77",
     "gender" -> "male", "vital date" -> "2008-11-14", "dead" -> "1", 
    "smoking" -> "2", "ps who" -> "0"|>, <|"GSMName" -> "GSM2142641", 
    "tumor (t) or normal (n)" -> "L890T", "stage tnm" -> "4", 
    "histology" -> "2", "surgery date" -> "2010-02-02", "age" -> "56",
     "gender" -> "female", "vital date" -> "2013-07-20", 
    "dead" -> "1", "smoking" -> "1", 
    "ps who" -> "1"|>, <|"GSMName" -> "GSM2142642", 
    "tumor (t) or normal (n)" -> "L511N", 
    "Custom" -> "30"|>, <|"GSMName" -> "GSM2142643", 
    "tumor (t) or normal (n)" -> "L532N", 
    "Custom" -> "30"|>, <|"GSMName" -> "GSM2142644", 
    "tumor (t) or normal (n)" -> "L561N", 
    "Custom" -> "31"|>, <|"GSMName" -> "GSM2142645", 
    "tumor (t) or normal (n)" -> "L563N"|>, <|"GSMName" -> 
     "GSM2142646", 
    "tumor (t) or normal (n)" -> "L566N"|>, <|"GSMName" -> 
     "GSM2142647", "tumor (t) or normal (n)" -> "L572N", 
    "Custom" -> "25"|>};
```

Note that not every row has exactly the same key, so I can't get a normal `Dataset` to export a `".xslx"` file:

```
Dataset[data]
```

[image]

Now I want to complete the missing key with an empty string and get a normal `Dataset` that I can use to export the `.xslx` file:
[image]
This is my current solution:

```
keyall=Union@@Keys[data];
data=Table[AssociateTo[row,Thread[Complement[keyall,Keys[row]]->""]],{row,data}];
Dataset[ResourceFunction["KeySortLike"][#,Keys[First[data]]]&/@data,MaxItems->{All,All}]
```

Is there a more appropriate method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dataset[KeyUnion[data, "" &], MaxItems -> {All, All}] (*thanks: SjoerdSmith*)
```

[image]

Comment: `KeyUnion[data, "" &]` is preferable to `ReplaceAll`

Comment: Thank you so much @SjoerdSmit; I will update.